# Custom plugins don't work if instructions for Debian users are used

Tags: neo4j, debian

I have developed my own extension (TransactionEventHandler) for the Neo4j. It worked fine before. But now, after reinstallation of the Neo4j, my plugin isn't work (no errors, but code isn't called - logs aren't contain any of my records).

I installed the Neo4j accordingly to [instructions for Debian users](http://debian.neo4j.org/?_ga=1.100821001.92216559.1455034890) (before I used an installation from a .tar.gz file). And I changed a version of Neo4j from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2.

**May be anyone have thoughts, why it's happening?**

Additional info:

1. I put my extension under /var/lib/neo4j/plugins/.
2. I tried to start the Neo4j as a service: `service neo4j-service start`; and using `./neo4j start` command. In both cases a result is the same - the code isn't called.

Comment: Is it an unmanaged extension or a server plugin? Could you be more specific about what is not working? Is there an error starting Neo4j?

Comment: @WilliamLyon There is no errors. Code just isn't called. It is a kernel extension: TransactionEventHendler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I wasn't able to resolve this issue. I'm just using .tar.gz again. That way all works as expected. So, I suggest to everyone to do the same if you encountered the same issue.

One more thing, which, I think, worth to be mentioned: if try to use .tar.gz after removing of Neo4j Debian packages, this approach won't work for some reason. I was forced to reinstall my Debian to make it working.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the permissions on the plugin file? I once had an issue where through moving my Neo4j installation around/SCPing, the permission on the plugin file made it so it wasn't executable. It needed to be chmod'ed.

Comment: Thanks for your thought. Unfortunately, it isn't help. I chowned all files under /plugin directory so, that they all are executable by any user. But nothing changed.

Comment: Hmmmm.I know it has been asked already, but you definitely confirmed there are no startup errors in console.log and messages.log (in the graph.db directory)?

Comment: Yes, there were no errors. But thanks again for your suggestions!